# Beagle Bone Black Audio Cape rev B synchronization issues

Tags: beagleboneblack

Basically the audio cape is working. Except for one strange phenomena that mistifies me. I will try to explain.

When I play a .wav file for example speaker-test -t vaw -> if lucky I hear Front Left - Front right as one expects. But 9 out of 10, I hear white noise with the audio front left front right very faint in the background or at another time the sound is simply distorted. The same happens when I play a file with aplay or mplayer.

So when I am lucky, or timing with respect to system clock is in sync I hear the audio clearly, if out of sync it might me white noise or distorted playback.

I have google extensively and have not found any solution. So I hope one of you guys knows whats happening here. It has to be something low level.

I'm quite a newby in this matter but according to this: [Troubleshooting Linux Sound](http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/sound/sound_troubleshooting.htm) all seams to work ok.

These are my system parameters and settings: root@beaglebone:~# lsb_release -a Distributor ID: Angstrom Description: Angstrom GNU/Linux v2012.12 (Core edition) Release: v2012.12 Codename: Core edition

```
root@beaglebone:~# cat /sys/devices/bone_capemgr*/slots 0: 54:PF---

1: 55:PF--- 
2: 56:P---L CBB-Relay,00A0,Logic_Supply,CBB-Relay
3: 57:PF--- 
4: ff:P-O-L Bone-LT-eMMC-2G,00A0,Texas Instrument,BB-BONE-EMMC-2G
5: ff:P-O-- Bone-Black-HDMI,00A0,Texas Instrument,BB-BONELT-HDMI
6: ff:P-O-L Bone-Black-HDMIN,00A0,Texas Instrument,BB-BONELT-HDMIN
7: ff:P-O-L Override Board Name,00A0,Override Manuf,BB-BONE-AUDI-02
root@beaglebone:~# speaker-test -t wav
```

speaker-test 1.0.25

Playback device is default Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 1 channels WAV file(s)        Rate set to 48000Hz (requested 48000Hz) Buffer size range from 128 to 32768 Period size range from 8 to 2048 Using max buffer size 32768 Periods = 4 was set period_size = 2048 was set buffer_size = 32768

0 - Front Left
Time per period = 0.641097

0 - Front Left
root@beaglebone:~# mplayer AxelF.wav MPlayer2 2.0-379-ge3f5043 (C) 2000-2011 MPlayer Team 162 audio & 361 video codecs

Playing AxelF.wav. Detected file format: WAV format (libavformat) [wav @ 0xb6082780]max_analyze_duration reached [lavf] stream 0: audio (pcm_s16le), -aid 0 Load subtitles in .

==============================================================[edit]
Forced audio codec: mad Opening audio decoder: [pcm] Uncompressed PCM audio decoder AUDIO: 44100 Hz, 2 ch, s16le, 1411.2 kbit/100.00% (ratio: 176400->176400) Selected audio codec: [pcm] afm: pcm (Uncompressed PCM)

==============================================================[edit]
AO: [alsa] 44100Hz 2ch s16le (2 bytes per sample) Video: no video Starting playback... A: 1.6 (01.6) of 15.9 (15.8) 0.3%

MPlayer interrupted by signal 2 in module: unknown

Exiting... (Quit)

Answer (score 1):

I can shed some light on what is causing the artifacts that you experience. I am sorry I do not yet have a countermeasure - I am struggling with the same problem. You describe the perceptible consequences pretty accurately.

Sound data travels from the ARM System on Chip to the Audio Codec on the audio cape using the [I2S](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2S) bus. I2S is a serial protocol, it sends one bit at a time, starting each sample with the most significant bit, then sending all bits down to the least significant bit. After the least significant bit of one sample is sent, the most significant bit of the sample on the next audio channel is sent. To be able to interpret the bit stream, the receiving audio codec needs to know when a new sound sample starts with its most significant bit, and also, to which channel each sound sample belongs. For this purpose, the "Word Select" (WS) signal is part of I2S and changes its value to indicate the start of the sound sample and also identifies the channel, see [this I2S timing diagram](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:I2S_Timing.svg) for a better understanding of the concept.

What you and I perceive on our not-quite-working audio capes can be fully explained by the bit stream being interpreted out-of-step by the audio codec:

When you hear loud noise and the target signal soft in the background, then one or more of the least significant bits of the preceding sample are interpreted as the most significant bits of the current sample. The more bits are shifted, the softer the target signal, until you might only perceive noise when (this is a guess!) about 4 bits are shifted.

When the shift is in the other direction, i.e. most significant bit of the current sample was interpreted as the least significant bit of the preceding sample, then what you hear will sound correct for soft parts of the signal, i.e. when the most significant bit is not actually used (this is a simplification, see below). For louder parts of the signal, e.g. drum beats, you will perceive the missing most significant bit as distortion. Of course, the distortion gets worse and starts at softer levels as more bits are shifted in this direction.

In the above paragraph, the most significant will change with the sign of the data, so the statement that it is not actually used is valid only insofar as the most significant bit will have the same value as the next most significant bit for soft sounds. See [Two's Complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) for an introduction how negative integers are represented in computers.

I am not sure, where the corruption occurs. It could be that the WS signal is not correctly interpreted by the Audio Codec on the cape, or the WS signal is not correctly sent by the ARM System-on-Chip, or the bit shift might happen already inside the ARM CPU, e.g. in the Alsa driver.